# Irrational Numbers Expression

Tags: irrational-numbers

Say *$x$* and *$y$* are irrational numbers.

I know that *$x + y$* could be rational, for example $\pi$ and $-\pi$.
Also, *x/y* could be rational, for example pi and 1/pi.

But would  *$x + y + xy$* be irrational? I couldn't find an example where the expression could be rational. Could someone find an example where the expression is rational, or give a proof of how it has to be irrational?

Comment: $x=\sqrt{2}$, $y=-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thank you, now that I see it, I can't believe I didn't think of it haha.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x+y+xy = (1+x)(1+y)  - 1$. Hence, if $x+y+xy$ is irrational, then so is $(1+x)(1+y)$. Furthermore,  $x$ and $y$ are assumed irrational, so $1+x,1+y$ are already irrational. Hence, $1+x,1+y$ are irrational numbers whose product is irrational.

This , as you know, need not happen all the time. For example, using the very common example $(\sqrt 2)^2 = 2$, one sees that $x = y = \sqrt 2 - 1$ would do the job here. Indeed, $x + y + xy = 1$ in this case.